# Authentication middleware error using Express, Jsonwebtoken, TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt

I am trying to use the authentication middleware based on `jsonwebtoken` library. After switching to TypeScript syntax, the middleware stopped working and throws "Invalid token, authorisation denied".
Below is the middleware code:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import jwt, { Secret } from "jsonwebtoken";

const SECRET_KEY: Secret = String(process.env.SECRET_KEY);
const AUTHORISATION: boolean = Boolean(process.env.AUTHORISATION) || true;

export default function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  if (!AUTHORISATION) next();
  const token = <string>req.headers["x-auth-token"];
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: "No token, authorisation denied" });
  }
  try {
    jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY, function (err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Invalid token, authorisation denied" });
      }
      next();
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: "Authentication error" });
  }
}
```

Autorisation route, returns the token:

```
app.get("/auth", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    jwt.sign(
      {
        id: 1,
      },
      SECRET_KEY,
      { expiresIn: "10h" }, // Expiration (optional)
      (err, token) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(token);
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
});
```

Route that uses the auth middleware:

```
app.post("/check", auth, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    res.json("Token is correct");
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send("Invalid token");
  }
});
```

The route accepts the token through headers as shown in the picture below:
[image]

If we replace the authentication function to the route, then no error is thrown as shown in the code below:

```
app.post("/check", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const token = <string>req.headers["x-auth-token"];
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY);
    if(decoded) res.json("Token is correct");
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send("Invalid token");
  }
});
```

An error in the console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.jwsDecode [as decode] (D:\projects\heroes\server\node_modules\jws\lib\verify-stream.js:71:20)
    at module.exports (D:\projects\heroes\server\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\decode.js:5:21)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (D:\projects\heroes\server\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:76:20)
    at default_1 (D:\projects\heroes\server\middleware\auth.ts:14:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\projects\heroes\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\projects\heroes\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\projects\heroes\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\projects\heroes\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\projects\heroes\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
```

Please tell me how to correctly implement the auth middleware? Thanks for attention!

Comment: What is the `auth` middleware? Can you share the code that defines it?

Comment: The first shown code is that i named "middleware". It is imported to the express route and passed as "auth"

Comment: Unlike `auth`, your replacement code does not throw an error if `decoded = false`.

Answer (score 1):

`jwt.verify` is a synchronous function (at least in `jsonwebtoken@8.5.1`).

Two things are missing from your implementation:

- Check the `exp` claim to detect expired tokens.
- If you want to authenticate a named user, read the `sub` claim (probably an email address) and write it into the `req` object for further processing.

```js
try {
  var payload = jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY);
  if (payload.exp && payload.exp <= new Date().getTime() / 1000)
    throw "token expired";
  req.user = payload.sub;
  next();
} catch (err) {
  res.status(401).json({ msg: "Authentication error" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to catch any error?

```js
jwt.verify(token, "SECRET_KEY", function(err, decoded) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
});
```

On the other hand, would you consider adding return before every res or next()

Comment: Would you consider adding `return` before every `res` or `next()`

Comment: If I replace the parameter SECRET_KEY with any string as '123' in both jwt.sign and jwt.verify, then everything works. Perhaps this is due to the SECRET_KEY variable (const SECRET_KEY: Secret = String(process.env.SECRET_KEY)). Please don't judge strictly, today is my first experience with Typeskript.

Comment: Nobody is judging buddy! Happy to hear that you have found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

`jwt.verify` is an asynchronous function, so it doesn't wait and goes to next line, so decode declaration would be (null | false) which never executes `next()` and thus parser goes to else block and sends response object `{ msg: "Token is not valid" }`.

Using async/await, you can wait for `jwt.verify` to complete and return values which will assign decode declaration, thus if condition will be true and `next()` gets executed.

Add await keyword before `jwt.verify` and async keyword at parent function, this might return success.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the reason is completely different. The `dotenv` package was imported incorrectly. The solution is corny:

> import "dotenv/config";

in `index.ts` file.

(Instead of `import dotenv from 'dotenv'` and `dotenv.config()`).

I did not see the elephant in the room. Excuse me if I misled people!